# Mate desktop does not display properly in CBL-Mariner Linux

Tags: linux, mate-desktop

I have been running MS CBL-Mariner Linux in vmware and I am able to compile, install, and run NsCDE, Lxde, and xfce properly. The only issue I have is that when I downloaded and compiled and installed mate (1.26.0), I have no desktop and an invisible mouse. Apparently, Mate is doing something different and displaying is different than other desktop environments. Anyone have a clue?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The specific problem is that the mate desktop is not showing. When I compiled and it installed it into /usr/local, the desktop is not complete. Accoring to the Mate website, they stated that I should compile and install the Mate 1.26 source into /opt/mate which I later did later. Now nothing shows up! When I execute mate-session, I get a blank screen after I execute it.

Comment: Have you tried installing the MATE components to `/usr/` directly. I think components like `mate-desktop` have to be installed there.

Comment: I tried installing all the Mate components to /usr instead of /opt and /usr/local and it gives me the same image as above! So, when I compile and install Mate 1.26.0 to /opt, it gives me nothing. When I compile and install Mate to /usr, it give me the exact weird desktop as illustrated above (when compiled in installed to /usr/local). It looks like I am missing Mate components?

Comment: The desktop is controlled by the caja file manager. Have you tried running it in your VM?

Comment: 1.26 does not appear to have a caja file manager. The older versions do but not the current version. Also, I did install it into /usr but I still get the same blank desktop. Either I am missing more mate components that are not listed in the https://pub.mate-desktop.org/releases/1.26/ or something else which I don't know!